# How can I write 2 select statements in CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, common-table-expression

This is my query which isn't proper:

```
;With normal As
    (   
        Select  ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by RecordingDateTime) as RowNum, 
                DocumentID, 
                CreatedByAccountID, 
                JurisdictionID,
                InstrumentID
            --  Cast(InstrumentID as decimal(18)) as InstrumentID
            From Documents  Where RecordingDateTime IS NOT NULL
    )
    Select Top 1 @PreviousInstrumentID = InstrumentID,
                @PreviousDocumentID = DocumentID,
                @PreviousCreatedByAccountID = CreatedByAccountID,
                @PreviousBelongsToJurisdictionID = JurisdictionID
            From normal
                Where RowNum = @RowNum - 1

    Select Top 1 @NextInstrumentID = InstrumentID,
                @NextDocumentID = DocumentID,
                @NextCreatedByAccountID = CreatedByAccountID,
                @NextBelongsToJurisdictionID = JurisdictionID
            From normal
                Where RowNum = @RowNum + 1
```

I want both the select statements to be under the context of CTE. How an I achieve that?

Comment: You **cannot** do this. The CTE is available for **one statement** only. If you need to preserve the result - you need to put it into a temporary table (or table variable) and then run your two statements against that

Comment: @marc_s: Thanks! Will table variable not be inefficient? I currently have 100K records in table and will increase over time. Please suggest your thoughts.

Comment: How is the output of this query consumed? Do you really need those variable assignments?

Comment: Yes, else I wouldn't have written the query.

Comment: Table variable is fine for a handful or rows - but with 100K, I'd go for a temporary table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could select both rows in a single statement and get the corresponding values using conditional aggregation:

```
With normal As
    (   
        Select  ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by RecordingDateTime) as RowNum, 
                DocumentID, 
                CreatedByAccountID, 
                JurisdictionID,
                InstrumentID
            --  Cast(InstrumentID as decimal(18)) as InstrumentID
            From Documents  Where RecordingDateTime IS NOT NULL
    )
SELECT
  @PreviousInstrumentID            = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum - 1 THEN InstrumentID       END),
  @PreviousDocumentID              = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum - 1 THEN DocumentID         END),
  @PreviousCreatedByAccountID      = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum - 1 THEN CreatedByAccountID END),
  @PreviousBelongsToJurisdictionID = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum - 1 THEN JurisdictionID     END),
  @NextInstrumentID                = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum + 1 THEN InstrumentID       END),
  @NextDocumentID                  = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum + 1 THEN DocumentID         END),
  @NextCreatedByAccountID          = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum + 1 THEN CreatedByAccountID END),
  @NextBelongsToJurisdictionID     = MAX(CASE RowNum WHEN @RowNum + 1 THEN JurisdictionID     END)
FROM normal
WHERE RowNum IN (@RowNum - 1, @RowNum + 1)
;
```

Comment: Nice.  I was going to suggest something like this, but thought it was less clear than the additional CTE method, and a bit harder to maintain.  But, looking at an earlier comment indicating the number of rows could be large, then maybe this is a better approach as it could save a scan of the results.

Comment: @GilM: On the other hand, if they ever needed to get RowNum-1 and RowNum+1 for more than @RowNum in one go, your suggestion would be much easier to transform: you would merely need to replace the CROSS JOIN with an `INNER JOIN ON next.RowNum = prev.RowNum + 2`. I'm not sure if my approach is at all scalable in that respect.

Comment: Er, that is, they would probably no longer use variable assignment, of course. But they might instead want to return those rows paired. Well, never mind, that's probably a too far-fetching supposition.

Comment: This works like a charm and is probably efficient too :). Thanks Andriy.

Comment: @Jack: Thank you. I'm not sure if it really is much better than GilM's solution in terms of performance. Maybe you could compare the two solutions after fixing GilM's as per my suggestion in the other comment?

Answer (score 3):

You could create two other CTEs, and use them in your select statement:

```
;With normal As
    (   
        Select  ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order by RecordingDateTime) as RowNum, 
                DocumentID, 
                CreatedByAccountID, 
                JurisdictionID,
                InstrumentID
            --  Cast(InstrumentID as decimal(18)) as InstrumentID
            From Documents  Where RecordingDateTime IS NOT NULL
    )
, PrevRow AS (
SELECT InstrumentID, DocumentID, CreatedByAccountID, JurisdictionID
FROM normal
WHERE RowNum = @RowNum - 1
), NextRow AS (
SELECT InstrumentID, DocumentID, CreatedByAccountID, JurisdictionID
FROM normal
WHERE RowNum = @RowNum + 1
)
Select Top 1    @PreviousInstrumentID = PrevRow.InstrumentID,
                @PreviousDocumentID = PrevRow.DocumentID,
                @PreviousCreatedByAccountID = PrevRow.CreatedByAccountID,
                @PreviousBelongsToJurisdictionID = PrevRow.JurisdictionID,
                @NextInstrumentID = NextRow.InstrumentID,
                @NextDocumentID = NextRow.DocumentID,
                @NextCreatedByAccountID = NextRow.CreatedByAccountID,
                @NextBelongsToJurisdictionID = NextRow.JurisdictionID

FROM PrevRow 
FULL OUTER JOIN NextRow ON 1=1
```

Comment: Excellent. This looks promising.

Comment: @GiiM: This approach works fine for normal scenarios but fails on edge cases. Say If I am on 0th record and no previous record. Because you have done Cross Join even next record wouldn't be returned because Select isn't executed due to Cross Join :(

Comment: @Jack: Ah, but that is easily amended. Try replacing the `CROSS JOIN` with `FULL JOIN ... ON 1=1`. (And if that does fix it, you might want to review your choice of an answer too.)

Comment: @AndriyM, it's funny that we were both arguing for the other's solution.  My son calls this a Canadian Standoff (like when nobody goes at a 4-way stop because they're all trying to let the others go first).

Comment: Nice picture, haha! :) But I indeed have my doubts with regard to my suggestion's efficiency. It uses grouping, which *must* be affecting performance. I'm just not sure to what extent, given it's just two rows that are being aggregated. Perhaps, it's a Canadian Standoff with a twist in this case: one driver trying to persuade a passer-by to help them to decide which driver it would be better to allow to go first. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do not need those variable assignments because you are somehow using the output of this query in a datareader, you can run just one CTE with:

RowNum = @Row + 1 OR RowNum = @Row - 1

This will give you a result with two rows and you can consume it however you like in the consuming code.

Comment: This isn't the answer. What if the table just has 1 row. How do I then decide whether the row is for previous or next?

Comment: I don't understand ... How are you populating the rownum variable? If you have one row, then wouldn't you always have that problem. Lets say there is one row and rownum() is 1. You will pass RowNum a value of 1, none of the queries will work. If you pass the RowNum a value of 2 then 1 will be returned. You can look at the row number column and if it less than the value that you sent in, it previous and it is next if it is greater.

Comment: Sorry, not exactly what I wanted. @RowNum is not a constant value of 1. It can be either 30000 or 27677 or any number that you can think of.

Comment: Yes, I understand. Lets say that the table has one row and you pass in a value of "@RowNum = 27677", what is the expected output? How are you getting the value for @RowNum?